# PowerShell loop issue

Tags: powershell

I've got a piece of code to check the status of a particular service and if the status is not "running" to start it. The variable seems to have the proper data before the if/else statement but it always defers to else even when I have one of the test server's service set to off.  It will report one service as running and one as stopped but will echo "It's Down" for both.

Thanks in advance for your help

```
    $Servers = get-content c:\scripts\list.txt
    $Servers|foreach {
$service = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $_ -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='Buildbot'" 
$status = Get-Service -ComputerName $_ -Name "Buildbot" | select Status
echo $status
if ($status -eq "Running") {"Its Up!"} else {"It's down"} 
    #$service.StartService()
    #"It should be up now"}
}
```

Comment: What happens with you change `| select Status` to `| select -expand Status`

Comment: Follow the suggestion from @Matt or use `$status.status -eq "Running"`, currently `$status` is an object, not a string.

Comment: PS U:\> C:\scripts\buildbotsvc_check.ps1
                                                                                                                                                                                   Status
-----------
Running
It's down
                                                                                                                                                                                   Stopped
It's down

Comment: Thank you gentlemen, acro444's suggestion did the trick.  I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure your issue is that you are doing a string comparison on an object with the property status as supposed a string of the status state. Update the line that populates `$status` like either of the following examples

```
$status = Get-Service -ComputerName $_ -Name "Buildbot" | select -ExpandProperty Status


$status = (Get-Service -ComputerName $_ -Name "Buildbot").Status
```

As an aid consider the output of the following two commands

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> Get-Service  -Name "Print Spooler" | select Status
 Status
 ------
Running

PS C:\Users\mcameron> Get-Service  -Name "Print Spooler" | select -expand Status
Running
```

The first result is an object with the property `Status`. Second is just a string.